# Django 1.8 image display issue in template file

Tags: python, django, image, django-views

I'm trying to like Django and use it for custom high traffic projects.  For this purpose, i'm doing tutorial tango with django. I've stuck with image display step.  Here my code:
settings.py file:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/images"),
    STATIC_URL,
]
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Rango says...</h1>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <img src="{% static "images/lwd.jpg" %}" alt="Picture of Rango" /><br />
        hello world! <strong>{{ boldmessage }}</strong><br />
        <a href="/rango/about/">About</a><br />
    </body>

</html>
```

And here is screenshoot of the result:
[not displayed image screenshoot](http://prntscr.com/9l0pu3)

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i even looked into documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/', # this should be file path not URL
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  yes, this fixed my problem.  Here solution:         # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/images"),
    'G:/Users/chris/tango_with_django_project/static',
]